# No sound in 12.04 on VirtualBox

Tags: 12.04, sound, virtualbox, live-cd, virtualization

No sound when installed in VirtualBox. When I boot from the live CD in Windows, sound works fine on my speakers. When in boot the live CD in VirtualBox it does not see my speakers. In sound properties only digital output built in S/PDIF and headphones!

I've done the pavcontrol - `alsamixer` -  all settings are OK. I've tried both 32/64 versions of Ubuntu. Running current version VirtualBox. System: Windows 7 64 - i5.

What am I overlooking?

Comment: Have you been able to resolve your problem?

Answer (score 11):

For a windows guest, Ubuntu host system, set the **VM** to use **ALSA** on the **host** and the **VM soundcard** to **Intel HD**.

Comment: +1. **Alsa on the host** fixed it for me - Ubuntu 14.10 host + Windows 7 guest

Comment: Alsa on host works, Host Ubuntu 18.04, Guest Windows 10 Lite

Comment: Also works for `Win 10` host, `Ubuntu 20.04` guest.

Answer (score 6):

Is your audio setting for your Ubuntu guest virtual machine set to `ICH AC97`?

`ICH AC97` is the only VirtualBox VM audio setting which allows me to get sound when running Ubuntu as a guest and either Windows or OS X (10.6.8) as the host.

In particular, if a VM's audio setting is `Intel HD Audio` then sound does **not** work in an Ubuntu 12.04 desktop guest.

On the other hand, sound will only work for a Windows 7 (64-bit) guest when the audio setting is `Intel HD Audio`. This can be rather annoying when you are working with a VM which dual boots either Ubuntu or Windows 7 as the guest OS.

I have never investigated this further to find out why it works this way or if there is a way to work around it. If you happen to find one, please let us know about it.

**Note:** You will have to "*power off*" your VM to change its audio setting.

Comment: Just curious - why are you dual-booting a VM? What advantage does that provide over having two separate VMs?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the VirtualBox Guest Additions by going to Devices> Install Guest Additions.  This usually fixes problems for Virtual Machines like audio and adds more features to the VM.

[image]

Comment: did that works OK. still NO sound.

Comment: You may need to *completely shut down the guest and start it up again* after doing this. That fixed it for me (while a simple reboot of the guest did not).

Answer (score 0):

Host system: Solaris 11.1,  VirtualBox guests: ubuntu 12.04, Windows 7, linux mint

- Host Audio driver: for ubuntu 11.04: OSS, for ubuntu 12.04: OSS
- Audio Controller: for ubuntu 11.04: Intel HD Audio, for ubuntu 12.04: ICH AC97
- Different audio controllers for different guests are not a problem, because under VB
  adjustments are individual for each machine.
- For me, sounds (including event sounds (beep etc.)) worked perfectly again, after
  switching to GNOME classic(No effects), but the event sounds are missing under ubuntu
  and GNOME classic.
- Works fine with OSS on the host, ALSA not required; applies to ALL guests.

Answer (score 0):

Host: Windoze 7 64-bit
Guest: Oracle Linux 2.6 - RedHat ES (like Fedora), KDE=4.3.4

Assuming Windows audio is working.

1. Shutdown and restart with the ICH AC97 as the 'audio' device.
2. If you have the loudspeaker/volumeControl in the icon/task bar, untick all the mute boxes and you might be done.
3. StartPenguin/systemSettings/Multimedia and test the "Default". Assuming it works, move "Default" to the top using the Prefer button in all options.
4. Goto step 2 and cross fingers.

For testing, use "aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav" as described elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

For me, forcing alsa to unload and reload worked:

```
alsa force-unload
alsa force-reload
```