# Ubuntu virtualbox guest doesn't see sound card

Tags: sound, virtualbox

I have a virtualbox guest running Ubuntu 14.04 (The host is Ubuntu 14.04 also). The virtual machine does not play audio.

Inside the guest :-

lspci shows my sound card, pavucontrol shows no sound cards present, ubuntu sound settings shows "dummy output" as the output.

In short... help !!

Does anybody know what I need to do in order to get sound working in a virtualbox ubuntu guest ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the VM Settings in VirtualBox. Right click on the VM (when it's shut down), click `Settings`, and check the `Audio` section. Make sure the Audio is Enabled, and to choose `ALSA` as the `Host Audio driver` [image: Screenshot of sound settings in VirtualBox].

This should work.

Comment: Already tried that, every permiatation,, for a good hour or so. Sti?ll no audio card configured on the vm.

Comment: According to [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/143396/no-sound-in-12-04-on-virtualbox), setting the Host Audio driver as `ALSA` would work.

If not you could install additions on Virtual Box to fix this issue.

Comment: Setting the host audio driver to ALSA does not fix my issue. As I say, I have tried every permutation. I have already installed additions.